# Microcontroller for embedded programming

Tags: embedded, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I live in a country where popular microcontrollers aren't easily available. The only ones i could find that were arm based were STM32F4 Discovery and STM32VL Discovery. The latter one is cheaper so that is preferable.

So the question is, am i looking in the right direction ? Are these microcontrollers specifically for embedded programming ? (I am a beginner) It would be really helpful if someone could set me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is quite difficult to give you a precise reply to this question as the choice between one microcontroller or another only depends on the application you want to address (and you don't give more information on your objectives in the question).

If it is only for an educational purpose, the STM32 discovery boards are IMO a very good choice because they are cheap and you don't need any other piece of hardware (like a JTAG programmer) to start playing with it (you only need an external power source).

Comment: I agree, these are a good choice, there are other good choices as well.  I have some examples that may or may not help you get started with these boards http://github.com/dwelch67  (stm32vld and stm32f4d).   The f4 has a lot more to it/on it, not a bad choices as a first one and the usb debugger interface is more mature than the vld.  there is an stlink github repo for linux based access to these boards if that is of interest.  stm has an m0 based board out at the vld board price, mine should be here any day, that is another alternative.

Comment: Yup, only for educational purposes. Upon some more search, I found ARDUINO UNO aswell. Thing is, i am really fascinated by programming. Learning it for a year now. So now, i want to start embedded programming for learning purposes.

Comment: I often recommend the msp430 launchpad, ships from Taiwan I think, asia basically so probably ships worldwide.  inexpensive but a good instruction set, easy to get up and running, etc...there a large arduino and even larger avr community, so the arduino family is not a bad place to start either, a bit pricy compared to the msp430 or the stm32 discovery boards.

Comment: the stm32f0 discovery is out for $8, just got mine, not a bad board...